# Sails.js datastore fails after some time

Tags: sails.js

I have configured my dummy Sails.js application to work with mysql database like so:

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
    url: 'mysql://mysql:mysql@localhost:3306/sails',
  }
};
```

and it works fine, both read and write operations work great. However, after some time http requests begin to fail with 500 code and the error is:

> AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: Could not run
> select() because of 2 problems:
>
> • "datastore" is required, but it was not defined.
>
> • "models" is required, but it was not defined.

While this is happening, I keep getting this error with every page refresh. If I kill the server and lift it again, the database works fine for some time. I couldn't find much on this error online. Not sure where to look for the solution.

Below is my package.json just in case

```
{
  "name": "ration",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "sails": "^1.5.0",
    "sails-hook-apianalytics": "^2.0.3",
    "sails-hook-autoreload": "^1.1.0",
    "sails-hook-organics": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^4.0.0",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^2.0.0",
    "sails-mysql": "2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "grunt": "1.0.4",
    "htmlhint": "0.11.0",
    "lesshint": "6.3.6",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {...},
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/anonymous node/sails user/ration.git"
  },
  "author": "anonymous node/sails user",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.13"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this problem was caused sails-hook-autoreload and I'm a bit ashamed I did not notice the pattern that causes this error every time the hook was triggered. I ended up using nodemon for automated server restarts and everything works fine. Hope this will help somebody out there.